# A complex analysis book with a lot of exercises?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am an undergrad student and this semester I took a complex analysis course. can anyone recommend $\mathbf {a \ complex\ analysis\ book\ with\ a\ lot\ of\ exercises?}$ I read Ahlfors's and Joseph Back's books but they only have a little number of exercises.

Course Content:

1. The Complex Plane: 
   Complex Numbers,
   Topology of the Complex Plane.
2. Complex Functions:
   Limits and Continuity,
   Analytic Functions,
   Cauchy-Riemann Equations,
   Harmonic Functions,
   Elementary Transcendental Functions.
3. Complex Integration:
   Complex-valued functions of real variables,
   Complex Line Integrals,
   Cauchy-Goursat Theorem,
   Cauchy Integral Formula,
   The Mean Value Property and the Maximum Modulus Principle.
4. Power Series:
   Series of Complex Numbers,
   Uniform Convergence,
   Power Series,
   Power Series Expansion of an Analytic Function,
   The Zeros of an Analytic Function.
5. Laurent Series and Isolated Singularities:
   Laurent Series,
   Isolated Singularities of Analytic Functions

Comment: You could use a textbook with a problem book.

Comment: @xbh any recommendations?

Comment: Maybe you can read E.M.Stein's book: complex analysis.

Comment: I have used Daniel Alpay's A complex Analysis Problem Book. Maybe you could take a look at it.

Comment: Hi - as an undergrad [Priestley](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Complex-Analysis-H-Priestley/dp/0198525621) was standard (at several unis in the uk e.g. Cambridge). Has lots of exercises though in some sense presentation perhaps slightly more elementary. I read Ahlfors too at the time for another perspective and the two worked well together. Covers most - actually probably all of the above (been a while!) as well as some topics like Fourier / Laplace transforms.

Comment: I seem to remember that Churchill (now Brown and Churchill) has lots of exercises.  Maybe you can take a look inside it on amazon.  But buy a cheap used copy.  The text material will be pretty simple for someone who's read Alfors.

Comment: *Brown and Churchill* is the best one.

Comment: If you are simply looking for lots of exercises, you might try Schaum's Outline of Complex Variables: inexpensive, not much theory, and tons of exercises.  Personally, I like "Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering and Science" by Saff and Snider for its emphasis on applications like evaluation of integrals.

Answer (score 3):

Try

> 1) Complex variables and applications by J.W.Brown and R.V.Churchill
>
> 2) Foundations of complex analysis by S.Ponnusamy

Both book contains a lot of good exercise problems for grow up the knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

You can read the following books, which have good number of exercises;

1. Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering, by Edward B. Saff (Author), Arthur David Snider
2. A First Course in Complex Analysis with Applications by D. G. Zill and P. D. Shanahan